# Laptop CPU overheating issue

Tags: cpu, gpu, asus-laptop, overheating, intel-core-i5

I have an i5-8250 (8th generation) laptop, with 8gb ram and GeForce MX150 2Gb. When I play games in low-medium settings my cpu temperature goes upto 80-85°C and GPU temperature around 70-75. Also both cpu and GPU has the same heat sink. Is this temperature something I should be worrying about ? Or is it normal. Previously , when I got the laptop it ran games like a charm without overheating.

Comment: Use compressed air to blow out dust and hair out of the cooling system of your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

**according to thanks to website smallbusiness**
https://smallbusiness.chron.com/safe-gpu-temperature-laptop-77827.html

> Generally, the safe temperature range to use a laptop is in temperatures between 50 to 95 degrees F, or 10 to 35 degrees C. If the graphics card temperature in your laptop gets too hot, it will normally reduce its power usage on its own until the temperature goes down.

**According to thanks to Gurcem Eugene Zekai answer in Toms hardware refereed website**

https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/whats-a-safe-temperature-for-a-gaming-laptop-based-on-cpu-gpu-msi-gs73vr.143787/

> Laptop GPUs are fine up to 60-70C and CPU can handle 100C

**According to thanks to Dylan Gomez answer in QUORA refereed website**

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-safe-temperature-range-for-a-laptop-GPU**

> For most GPUs the safe temperatures are below 75° C or 167° F. The temperatures that are too high is 80° C or 176° F. Most GPUs can survive being at temperatures of up to 90° C or 194° F but temperatures higher than 80° C should be avoided because they can  damage the GPU.

**According to thanks to Photonboy answer in website tomshardware**

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/laptop-gpu-overheating.2027304/

Reasons for overheating GPU:

1, Using of CPU and GPU is more than normally would.

2. The cooling fan of laptop and CPU/GPU is defective slow or not working
3. Heatpipe or other parts of cooler is not working or may be corrosion or damaged.
4. Dust in CPU/GPU Fan heatsink or FAN of laptop.
5. Thermal Paste may be dried
6. Airflow getting blocked in Laptop.
7. Power settings
8. Overclocking of CPU /GPU  or VGA or RAM

**Solutions modified According to My knowledge and  referred text  from the solutions provided in various site links**

thanks to KryssNova in tomshardware
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/laptop-gpu-overheating.2027304/

thanks to photonboy in tomshardware
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/laptop-gpu-overheating.2027304/

SOLUTIONS

1. Clean the dust in laptop
2. Use thermal paste
3. Clean the heat sink
4. Clean the Fans cooler pipes or cooling parts if any
5. Check CPU/GPU is overclocked in BIOS or software
6. Check if CPU/GPU is not overused by any Games or any software
7. Find a large heat sink or fan for GPU and laptop if it can fit as per size (check cooler master site they have many solutions)

https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/coolers/notebook-cooler/notepal-x3/

https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/coolers/?filter=50126/#!/Cooler%20Type=Notebook%20Cooler

8. get a laptop cooling pad like this :

http://www.newegg.ca/Laptop-Cooling-Pads/SubCategory/ID-319

- check Power Options setting
- If on High Performance
- Power Options>Change Plan Settings>Change Advanced Power Settings>Processor Power Management check all the tabs,

  · Tab : Minimum Processor State
          set to "5%" on both
        dont run your CPU running at Max performance 
        at all times without reason use when needed

  · Tab : System Cooling Policy

  ```
       set to "Active" on both, 

       dont run your CPU to run without cooling.
  ```

  · Tab : Maximum Processor State

  ```
       set to "100%" on both
  ```

  · click "Apply".

  · heat sink for CPU and GPU is probably connected 
     together, it could be that the heat sums up 
     together.
- 3D settings of Geforce Control Panel (install Graphic card softwares), then you want to try changing Power Managment Mode to "Adaptive".

  9. VSYNC power heating options

     ```
     (1) Run FRAPS and the game

     (2) Turn off VSYNC

     (3) Tweak averaging at least 10% above the 
         target refresh (i.e. 66FPS)

     (4) Turn on VSYNC
     ```

Comment: @Mokubai as per link How to reference material written by others. https://superuser.com/help/referencing  i had referred and thanked to the refereed site hope this modifications is acceptable and satisfied MODERATORS

Answer (score -1):

Overheating is normally caused by the cooling system not transferring the heat to the fan.
The fans job is to blow the hot air out of the laptop.
Usually over time the thermal paste becomes hard preventing proper heat transfer from the CPU to the heatsink.
Cleaning the contacts and applying new thermal paste should fix it.
Also clean the dust which usually builds up in the fan.

Comment: Cleaning _what_ contacts?

Comment: **You should never clean the contacts of a Intel CPU socket.**

Comment: My apologies, my wording was wrong. I didn't mean the contacts that connect to the motherboard. I meant the metal at the top of the CPU that the heatsink is in contact.